# Reassigning a variable to another variable in a while loop in python

Tags: python, variables

```
hint = str
low = 0
high = 100
guess = (high + low)/2



answer = int(raw_input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100: "))

while (True):

    print "Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?"
    hint = raw_input("H, L, or C: ")
    hint = hint.lower()
    while (hint != "h" and hint != "l" and hint != "c"):
        print "invalid option"
        hint = raw_input("H, L, or C: ")
        hint = hint.lower()

    if (hint == "h"):
        low = guess
        print "newlow: " + str(low)
        print "newGuess: " + str(guess)     
    elif (hint == "l"):
        high = guess
    elif (hint == "c"):
        print "Correct, the answer was " + str(answer)
        break
```

Why is the variable guess not being changed, i'm expecting low to change to 50, therefore newGuess would become 75, correct?

Comment: Variables don't change just because you change one of the variables you initially used to declare them. They're values, not formulas.

Comment: `low` does change, but you never assign a new value to `guess`, so it doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the moment when your program enters the `while` loop, all variables are set unless otherwise reassigned.

What you've done is reassigned your `low` variable. But, because the loop already has the value of `guess` in it using the *old* value for `low`, you would need to re-assign `guess` again, using the new one. Try putting your definition for `guess` *inside* the first `while` loop, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `guess` is never changed. In order to have it change you would have to put the declaration of `guess` in the while loop. For instance:

```
hint = str
low = 0
high = 100
guess = (high + low)/2

answer = int(raw_input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100: "))
while (True):

    print "Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?"
    hint = raw_input("H, L, or C: ")
    hint = hint.lower()
    while (hint != "h" and hint != "l" and hint != "c"):
        print "invalid option"
        hint = raw_input("H, L, or C: ")
        hint = hint.lower()

    if (hint == "h"):
        low = guess
        print "newlow: " + str(low)
        print "newGuess: " + str(guess)     
    elif (hint == "l"):
        high = guess
    elif (hint == "c"):
        print "Correct, the answer was " + str(answer)
        break
    guess = (high + low)/2#For instance here
```

This would refresh the variable `guess` every time the loop loops.
In this sample I made it so `guess` refreshes after you declare `low` and `high` as `guess`, if you wanted `low` and `high` to be declared as the new value of `guess` you would put the declaration before the `if` statements.

If you have any questions feel free to ask in the comments.
Hope this helps.